# Heroku Rails development vs. production

Tags: postgresql, heroku

While developing I tend to modify existing migrations instead of adding new ones. That keeps the clutter down, and as long as I have no data I care about this works very nicely. While developing I do a `rake db:migrate:reset` to delete the database and re-run all the migrations from scratch.

I tried doing this:

```
heroku pg:reset
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

and that didn't work. How should I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always follow this step if I mess up with migration like you did.

To drop the database:

```
$ heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE --confirm NAME_OF_THE_APP
```

To recreate the database:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

**Final step (you need to do this in order to make your app sync with DB)

```
$ heroku restart
```

Comment: Restart! That was what i was missing. Thanks :)

Comment: please click on check box next to my answer so i can get points to answer.

Comment: Yeah I was waiting for the 5 minutes delay :)